# Regex pattern failing

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to strip out all things that are in a string that are not a letter number or space so I created the regex

```
private static Regex _NonAlphaChars = new Regex("[^[A-Za-z0-9 ]]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

however When I call `_NonAlphaChars.Replace("Scott,", "");` it returns `"Scott,"`

What am I doing wrong that it is not matching the `,`?

Comment: The problem is that you can't nest character classes like that. So that regex you have actually gets parsed as: any character in the negated set `[^[A-Za-z0-9 ]` (where the second `[` is actually part of the class) followed by a single `]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did something funny with the double bracketing.  Change it to just

```
[^A-Za-z0-9 ]
```

Dropping your original expression into [The Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/) explained your regex as:

> The regular expression is a sequence consisting of the expression '[[^A-Za-z0-9 ]' and the character ']'.

For contrast, the explanation of the alternative I wrote is:

> The regular expression is a character class representing everything but the range of characters from the character 'A' to the character 'Z', the range of characters from the character 'a' to the character 'z', the range of characters from the character '0' to the character '9', and the character ' '.

Comment: Thanks for the link to The Regex Coach! I always have just been trying to do research on www.regular-expressions.info to figure out my expressions.

Answer (score 5):

```
private static Regex _NonAlphaChars =
    new Regex("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", RegexOptions.Compiled);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
[^A-Za-z0-9\s]
```

or

\W